# how to autocomplete library class function in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing a C++ command line project.  I used to use netbean.  For example if I use a string, then I should be able to invoke the string library API function in a popup list for me to choose to autocomplete.  So now I don't know how to do that in Xbox.  Can some one help?  My question is specific: how to find out the library function API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

press Esc can make auto-completion, but I am not sure whether it could cope with C++ in Xcode.